# How can I "colour" specific part of the screen using coordinates?

Tags: javascript

I'm just started working with Leap Motion (it is so much fun). The Leap works mainly with vectors. And now I want to create a program where I can visualise where is a vector pointing. The only way I can imagine doing this is by using a small image which appears when this fuction is on and positioning by using the img.style.left , img.style.top instructions. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with the Leap or the libraries you're using, but if your intention is to draw this on a flat 2D plane it would probably be easiest to convert the reference vectors to 2D coordinates and draw whatever you're aiming to draw using elements of the DOM. You could also look into using webGL or a webGL library like three.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to represent 2D Vectors,
You can use canvas to draw lines.

A canvas is like a div but you can draw whatever you want in it, I don't know anything about Leap Motion but if you want to draw lines and circles at precise coordinates, it may be a good solution instead of working with the DOM itself.

The JS part looks like this :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('my-canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//For exemple here is how to draw a rectangle
//fillStyle support all valid css color
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(50, 255, 24, 0.7)";
//Create the rectangle, with (startX, startY, height, width)
ctx.fillRect(20, 15, 50, 50);

ctx.beginPath(); //Tells canvas we want to draw
ctx.moveTo(250,250); //Moves the cursor to the coordinates (250, 250);
ctx.lineTo(75, 84); //Draws a line from the cursor (250, 250) to (75, 84);
ctx.closePath(); //Tells canvas to 'close' the drawing

ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.stroke(); //Draws the line stroke
```

And the HTML is simply :

```
<canvas id="my-canvas" height="500px" width="500px">
    Here is the text displayed when the browser doesnt support canvas.
</canvas>
```

I made a jsfiddle to show you what simple things we can do with canvas.
http://jsfiddle.net/pq8g0bf0/1/

A nice website to learn canvas : http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-element/

Since it's javascript, you are free to do calculations for your vectors coordinates, addding eventListeners etc ...